# PayPal Payflow Pro not allowing user to buy product

Tags: commerce, entities, payment-gateways

when I enable (and try to use) PayPal Payments Advanced and Payflow Link sub-module of Paypal module and submit the product form I get this error:

```
messageEntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property 
commerce_customer_address. in EntityStructureWrapper-
>getPropertyInfo() (line 335 of 
/site/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

When I remove Payflow Link module I do not get this error.

**The problem occurs when I remove the default 'address' field from the Customer Profiles > Billing Information and instead just use my own fields**...but I don't want to use that default address field because it contains items I don't want.

Anyone know how I can fix this so i can use Payflow?

It appears to be a problem in the Entity module but only gives me an error when trying to use Payflow Pro to purchase a product.

This is what that line of the entity module file has:

```
  public function getPropertyInfo($name = NULL) {
    $this->spotInfo();
    if (!isset($name)) {
      return $this->propertyInfo['properties'];
    }
    if (!isset($this->propertyInfo['properties'][$name])) {
      throw new EntityMetadataWrapperException('Unknown data property
```

' . check_plain($name) . '.');
        }
        return $this->propertyInfo['properties'][$name] + $this-

> info['property defaults'] + $this->propertyInfoDefaults;
>         }

Comment: Have you tried disabling the module, uninstalling it, and the reinstalling it? Anything in the issue queue?

Comment: Hi, yes I did try that...with the PayPal module. I've decided to just rebuild the site from scratch STARTING with the commerce modules and adding one thing at a time until I figure out what's causing the issue. Thanks for your response. I'll update the thread when I figure it out.

Comment: @nvahalik ok I updated my question above with my results. See the text in bold. It happens because I removed the default 'address' field...any thoughts on how to circumvent this or make the default address field NOT be required?

Comment: What items do you not want? You know you can customize that field and/or just hide unwanted elements using form_alters or CSS...

Comment: Well, I added some extra fields and I'd also like to re-order the fields. Right now 'country' is at the top. I want a custom field called title at the top, followed by the name, followed by 'organization' (another custom), then the address fields and THEN 'phone' and 'email'. So basically I really just want to re-order the fields. Is this easy to do?

Comment: Rearranging fields is easy. I'm not sure about *adding* fields.

Comment: I'll be using hook_form_alter to redo the order of fields as you suggested. Moreover I just added new fields in customer profile > billing information. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one but me seems to have encountered this problem. But in the oft-chance someone ever does encounter it, here's why.

This error is occurring because I had removed the default address field from the customer profile > billing information in my drupal commerce store in favor of custom fields. But you apparently HAVE to use the default dynamic address field, or at least I don't know a way around it.

Since most of those fields are valuable anyway, and I just wanted them really in a different order, I found it valuable to KEEP that field, add some custom fields as well, and then just re-order them using hook_form_alter() and the '#weight' property of each form element. Additionally using this function you may also hide any of the fields in the default address field (it contains multiple fields) that you don't want.